# I can´t modify color component in a BufferedImage

Tags: java, steganography

i want to modify color components i don´t know how can i do, could someone help me? I have tried this:

```
posX = 20;
posY = 10;
int srcPixel = image.getRGB(posX, posY);
Color c = new Color(srcPixel);
// I want to change Red component, for example,
valR = c.getRed();   //valR = 220; (for example)
valG = c.getGreen();
valB = c.getBlue();
valMod = valR - 1;

Color c2 = new Color(ValMod,valG,valB);
//my BufferedImage is imagenL

imagenL.setRGB(posX,posY,c2.getRGB());
```

Help me please.

Thank, you guys!

Comment: Your code looks fine, but you mention in the title you *can't* modify the color. Why? Do you possibly get an error? Maybe an IllegalArgumentException that you're not telling us about?

Comment: i can´t do it because when i want to see another time what is the red component in the same coordenate(posx,posy) i dont know why but another time the number is 220 and it shuld be 219.

Comment: Can you show us a [minimal version of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you attempt to change the color but it doesn't take effect? Are you telling me in the code above if I did `imagenL.getRGB(posX, posY);` at the end and extracted the red component that it'd still be 220?